# Apache Virtual Host incorrect document root

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, apache-2.4, virtualhost, https

I'm trying to set up two websites on the same IP using virtual hosts on Apache/Ubuntu. If this info is relevant, *SITE 1* is using https while *SITE 2* only http.

My issue is that *SITE 2* will load the document root of *SITE 1* instead of its own, along with inheriting the *https* even though I type *http.*

I sincerely have no idea what I'm doing, and everything suggested in similar threads either did not work or I didn't understand - hopefully there's something obviously wrong in my config files replicated below:

> **SITE1**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site1.com
    Redirect permanent / h t t ps://site1.com ## ignore spacing ##
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin info@site1.com
    ServerName site1.com
    ServerAlias www.site1.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/site1/public_html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/site1/certificate.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/site1/private.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/site1/ca_bundle.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

> **SITE 2**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin info@site2.com
    ServerName site2.com
    ServerAlias www.site2.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/site2/public_html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

> **Running apache2ctl -S returns the following**

```
VirtualHost configuration: 
*:443 site1.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/site1.conf:5)
*:80 is a NameVirtualHost
default server site1.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/site1.conf:1)
port 80 namevhost site1.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/site1.conf:1)
port 80 namevhost site2.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/site2.conf:1)

ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling-refresh: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-cache: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/var/run/apache2/" mechanism=default 
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33
Group: name="www-data" id=33
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you find any solution?